# SQLite ORDER BY result of nested query

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-order-by, subquery

I have a table with multiple date fields, and I would like to select the rows with the dates closest to the current date, regardless of which column it is.

There are 2 tables in the database;
Covers:

```
create table covers (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "stallionName integer not null, mareName integer not null, firstCoverDate text not null, lastCoverDate text not null, "
        + "scan14Date text not null, scan28Date text not null, foalingDate text not null, inFoal integer not null, notes text not null," +
        "FOREIGN KEY (stallionName) REFERENCES horses (_id), FOREIGN KEY (mareName) REFERENCES horses (_id))
```

stallionName and mareName are integers that reference the row _id of the relevant horse in the horse table (As such, the SQL query has multiple joins to get the names for the stallion and mare, instead of just the row _id). All date columns are of the form 'YYYY-MM-DD'

and horses:

```
create table horses (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "name text not null, type integer not null, birthDate text not null, vaccineDate text not null, "
        + "inFoal integer not null, notes text not null)
```

type is an integer referencing a spinner position (type is either mare, stallion, gelding etc)

I want to select 5 rows from the covers table with values of scan14Date, scan28Date and foalingDate that are nearest to today's date (i.e. the 5 most urgent rows)

This is my effort so far;

```
SELECT covers.* horses1.name AS stallionNameText, horses2.name AS mareNameText
FROM horses horses1 JOIN covers ON horses1._id = covers.stallionName JOIN horses     horses2 ON horses2._id = covers.MareName
WHERE covers._id IN

(SELECT DISTINCT _id FROM

(SELECT covers.scan14Date AS date, covers._id
FROM covers
WHERE date > dateToday
UNION

SELECT covers.scan28Date AS date, covers._id
FROM covers
WHERE date > dateToday

UNION

SELECT covers.foalingDate AS date, covers._id
FROM covers
WHERE date > dateToday

ORDER BY date)
LIMIT 5)
```

(It can be assumed that 'dateToday' is also of the form YYYY-MM-DD. It's sorted out in java)

Now, the nested query below successfully selects the 5 'most urgent' row _ids;

```
(SELECT DISTINCT _id FROM

(SELECT covers.scan14Date AS date, covers._id
FROM covers
WHERE date > dateToday
UNION

SELECT covers.scan28Date AS date, covers._id
FROM covers
WHERE date > dateToday

UNION

SELECT covers.foalingDate AS date, covers._id
FROM covers
WHERE date > dateToday

ORDER BY date)
LIMIT 5)
```

And the first section successfully gets all the data for the row _id selected above;

```
SELECT covers.* horses1.name AS stallionNameText, horses2.name AS mareNameText
FROM horses horses1 JOIN covers ON horses1._id = covers.stallionName JOIN horses     horses2 ON horses2._id = covers.MareName
WHERE covers._id IN
....
```

The issue I'm having is that the order of the row _ids returned by the nested query is lost in the overall query. If for example the nested query returns the row _ids (6, 3, 4, 12, 15) the overall query displays it in the order (3, 4, 6, 12, 15)

I would then like to return the stallion name, mare name, lastCoverDate, 14ScanDate, 28ScanDate and foalingDate.

My question is how can I maintain the order returned by the inner query? I naively tried to add ORDER BY date at the very end, but it predictably says there is no such column.

Thankyou for taking the time to read.

(Also, I'm sure that my SQL query won't be the most efficient way of doing it, but I'm fairly new to all this)

Answer (score 0):

Include the date in the result of the inner query, then you can order by date in the outer query. Your Java wrapper can simply ignore the date field in the result.

Comment: Thankyou for taking the time to respond. Unless I've misinterpreted what you meant (altering it to SELECT DISTINCT _id, date FROM ... ), this then leads to an error due to the clause "WHERE covers._id IN"
The error message is "Query Error: only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression Unable to execute statement"
From this I assume the nested query can only return 1 column?

Comment: Rather than use IN, use another INNER JOIN on _id with the (SELECT DISTINCT date, _id FROM ...).

Comment: Sorry for the delay, this project has been pushed to the back for the foreseeable future. Thankyou for all your advice, I'll try experimenting again when time allows